# Função "Onclick" que chame função PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Fala galera blz? sou iniciante em desenvolvimento e estou com um problema, tenho um formulário (HTML) que envia dados para um arquivo PHP e registra no banco de dados.

O que preciso é: Ao obter sucesso no registro dos dados, exibir na pagina "index" (a que possui o formulario) um alerta personalizado em JQUERY (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), já tentei de diversas maneiras porém não consegui. alguém me ajuda plzzz.

HTML:

```
<form action="cadastrar.php" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Escreva o seu e-mail">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Cadastrar</button>
                </form>                         </div>
```

php:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email)
VALUES ('$email')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $var =  $var = "<script language= 'JavaScript'>
  location.href='index.html'
  </script>";
  echo $var;
} 
else {
    echo "Esse email ja esta cadastrado";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

PS: Abreviei o código.

PS2: Sei que poderia fazer com ajax, mas não faço ideia como.

Answer (score 1):

Com AJAX você faria assim:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Escreva o seu e-mail">
              </div>
              <button id="cadastrar" class="btn btn-info">Cadastrar</button>
            </form>
```

(Tirei o submit do form para que o ajax siga sem mudar de página)

Depois o código jQuery:

```
$('#cadastrar').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cadastrar.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {email: $('#email').val()},
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 'true') { // voce deve dar um echo 'true' no PHP caso seja salvo
                //Coloque aqui seu código para invocar o alerta personalizado
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, uma dúvida que é até boba. Esse código Jquery eu coloco em qual parte do código? crio um arquivo separado? Como vou "chamar" ele no index após dar o true no PHP?

Comment: no arquivo HTML você pode incluir ele dentro de uma tag <script> (codigo jquery aqui) </script> ou criar um arquivo separado e importar ele pela tag script tambem: <script src='arquivo_externo.js'></script>.

Comment: Quanto ao 'chamar ele no index', note que o código ajax possui uma variavel 'url' que já esta direcionando para o seu arquivo php. Lá no php voce tem que fazer a sua lógica de salvar o email no banco, e quando voce der um 'echo' no PHP ele vai retornar esse echo para o seu codigo jquery. (Por isso só dê echo no que for necessário)

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma alternativa para o AJAX, postado em outra resposta.

Não é uma boa prática utilizar `location.href` junto com o código *PHP*. Para redirecionamentos você pode utilizar a função `header`.

**PHP:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('$email')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $url = "index.html?success=true&msg=Sucesso";
} 
else {
  $url = "index.html?success=false&msg=Insucesso";
}

$conn->close();
header("Location: ${url}");

?>
```

No *HTML* você pode utilizar um código para verificar os parâmetros da *URL*, por exemplo: `success`, `msg` etc.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="cadastrar.php" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
    <!-- Código aqui -->
</form>

<script>
window.location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach( data => {
    [param, value] = data.split("=");

    if (param == "success" && value == "true") {
        alert("Código para abrir o 'dialog'")
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá,
Tente fazer um require "index.html" dentro do if
assim:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    require "index.html"
}
```